# trouble with js word-break break-all usage with punctuation in chrome

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following example in jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/27L545rr/3/

```
<div contenteditable='true' style='word-break: break-all;'>
Word-break should cause just the extra character to wrap.  But just keep adding periods at the end until you wrap to see the bad char wrap.  All the periods AND the last letter wrap, this seems like a bug.
</div>
```

It's just a contenteditable with the word-break property set to 'break-all'.  As expected, if I type a long word, it will break on the character and just continue on the next line.  However if I add a series of punctuation to cause the break, (.,'! etc), instead of just the punctuation appearing on the next line, it drags the last non-punctuation letter as well, totally unexpected.  This seems like a bug, but is there a solution to force the break to happen at just the last character at the end of the line?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in **Google Chrome**. Not in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#break-all) it is working as intended. The spec states for **break-all**:

> In addition to ‘normal’ soft wrap opportunities, lines may **break between any two letters**  (except where forbidden by the ‘line-break’ property). Hyphenation is not applied. [Link](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#break-all)

And further:

> A **letter** for the purpose of this specification is a character belonging to one of the Letter or Number general categories in Unicode. [Link](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#letter0)

So, since periods, exclamation marks, commas and other punctuation marks are not considered *letters* it pulls the last letter down into the next line even if there's a series of non-letters. The behavior you are seeing is not a bug, but the correct implementation of the specification.

Comment: @KarlRim Yup. That's exactly what the spec says. Since a period, comma and other punctuation marks are not a *letter* and the specification says lines may break between *two letters* the break occurs between the last two letters *before all the extra punctuation marks.* In your comment example, between the last two g's.

Comment: Argh, that's terrible.  I don't suppose there any way to force it NOT to do that and just on any character rather than just letters?

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to put `&shy;` betwenn all characters with javascript. You would have to update it when text is inserted, deleted, changed or copied.

Problem: When pressing backspace, it would only delete a character every second time. You would have to fix that, too.

All in all, I guess it would be really ugly, but it could work. (If that's worth it)

Comment: you're correct Firefox works correctly. I tried adding the &shy; character, however the hyphen becomes visible on the line break, which breaks my use case.  I just wanted it to wrap invisibly.

Comment: Actually if I switch to \u2063, the invisible separator, it seems to do what I want, but of course I have to handle the case of this extra invisible character now.  But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Actually ended up embedding <wbr> word break tag.  Seems to work better and I don't have to alter the text nodes